# Proof Verification for showing $e^x$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I would like some feedback on my attempt / whether or not this is a valid approach as it differs from the other solutions I have been able to find. I am aware that similar questions have been asked about this question before, however, the solutions are different to mine and so I would like to know if this approach is valid.

**Question**

> Prove $e^x$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

**Attempt**

Consider a proof by contradiction, where we assume that $e^x$ is uniformly continuous and therefore satisfies for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that for real numbers $x$ and $y$:

$$|x-y|<\delta \implies |e^x-e^y|<\epsilon$$

We now consider $y=x+\frac{\delta}{2}$ which allows the LHS of the  inequality to be satisfied.

Therefore, this should imply that:

$$|e^x-e^{x+\frac{\delta}{2}} |<\epsilon \iff|e^x(1-e^{\frac{\delta}2})|<\epsilon$$

This should hold for any real value of $x$. And so if we let $x=0$ then this inequality simplifies to:

$$|(1-e^{\frac{\delta}2})|<\epsilon$$

And so if we fix $\epsilon = 0.5|(1-e^{\frac{\delta}2})|$ then this contradicts the inequality above.

Therefore, we have shown that $e^x$ is not uniformly continuous by contradiction. $\Box$

*I would be grateful for any feedback and guidance on ways in which I can improve the proof attempt.*

Comment: Could I instead choose my value of $x$ in terms of delta? @SacAndSac

Comment: You can’t choose $\epsilon$ in terms of $\delta.$ $\delta$ always varies in terms of $\epsilon.$ Otherwise, you could use this argument to prove $e^x$ is not even continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\delta$ you choose depends on the $\varepsilon$ so you can't take $\varepsilon$ in terms of $\delta$.

However, if you fix $\varepsilon >0$ and suppose that there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |e^x-e^y|<\varepsilon.$$
Take $y=x+\delta/2$ as you did, and now you can let $x$ tend to $+\infty$ to obtain a contradiction :
$$\varepsilon\geq \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}e^x|1-e^{\delta/2}|=+\infty.$$

Comment: Even easier, just prove no $\delta$ works for $\epsilon=1.$

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to take back his notations

Comment: How would this argument go? I fixed $\epsilon =1$ and assumed $x>y$ without loss of generality, then $x<\delta +y$. My aim was to then substitute something in for either $x$ or $y$ to get an expression for something less than epsilon, however, using this inequality doesn't allow me to substitute and still assume that the RHS will be less than epsilon. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: You’d show that for any $\delta>0$ there is some $x$ such that $|e^{x+\delta/2}-e^x|\geq 1=\epsilon.$ @FD_bfa

Comment: Would that involve you having to define a specific value of $x$ in terms of delta such that the inequality is satisfied? Or is it enough to just state it from there? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: If you want more of an answer, you shouldn’t have given a check mark to an answer. Checking an answer means you are done and satisfied with the answer. @FD_bfa But no, you need to show that $x$ exists. My comment is not meant to be a complete proof.

Comment: In particular, you are going to need to know *some* properties of $e^x.$ So far, my comment could be applied to any function. @FD_bfa

Answer (score -5):

Choose the sequence $\log(n+1)$ and $\log n$ and this two are parallel sequences but $e^{\log(n+1)}$ and $e^{\log n}$, not to be a parallel sequences, so that's why $e^x$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Read the question, not the title.